# Export all stack traces from Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, stack-trace, google-console-developer

Google Developer console allows to export crash report by some period of time as *.csv file. This file may be even accessed by `gsutil`, but this file do not contain full stack traces - only links to pages on which stacktrace is printed. Something like this:
 [image: stacktrace expample]

So questions are:

1. Is there any option in Google Developer Console which allows to export full stack traces?
2. Is there any instrument/Google Developer Console API which allows to download this stack traces?
3. If both previous question - which instrument is better to use to parse html with stack trace to extract it

P.S. We use Google Developer Console as main instrument to analyze crashes. There are better alternatives... but this question not about them

Comment: Could you please explain how to download the crashes .csv from Google Play? I can't find this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had not found any solution, I wrote a simple python program which download stacktraces by links from *.csv. Csv file with links to stacktraces you can easily download from google play (even automatically)

Program is emulating browser with cookies and javascript to be able to receive desired page and after thet parses html - so solution is not reliable

Here is the link to [programm](https://github.com/SKART1/SLGooglePlay)

Comment: The link no longer works.